# how to use CodeIgniter's order_by method?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to check if the order_by method implemented in CodeIgniter? i tried with several variations on the code below, none of which worked

```
 function getPRs(){
    $this->db->from('press_releases');
    $this->db->order_by('sort_order', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
 }
```

any help on this would be greatly appreciated!, thanks

Comment: what do you ve on sort_order??

Comment: do you want to check if order_by is implemented or not?? or you want to know how to use it?? because your title and question ve two different meanings

Comment: Is `sort_order` a column in your `press_releases` table?

Comment: yes, sort order is column of unique integers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code once.

```
    $this->db->select('*');        
    $this->db->from('press_releases');        
    $this->db->order_by('sort_order', 'asc'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: thank you, i did a var_dump and on the var and that seems to work.there is something in my subsequent code that is causing an error, even a simpler version, as stated above, doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function getPRs(){
    $this->db->order_by('sort_order', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get('press_releases');
    return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately, that is not working. i wish it was ;-)i'm getting:Call to a member function result() on a non-object in

Comment: in the controller i'm getting an error ->Call to a member function result() on a non-object in. if the function is simply this...function getPRs(){return $this->db->get('press_releases'); it works, so i dont' there's any problems in the controller